# Display image in a cocoa status app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, nsstatusitem

Hi I developed a cocoa status app. when I put a long title for example , it can't be shown and if i put an image as icon too it can't be shown , but if i put a small title it works correctly.
How can I fix this problem and make the image shown?

```
statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] 
    statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength] retain];    

[statusItem setMenu:menu]; 
//[statusItem setTitle:@"Notif "]; 
[statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"image"]]; 
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
```

Comment: Some suggestions please?

Comment: Hum, you want to show an image in the menu or in the statusBar ?

Answer (score 9):

Basically

```
NSStatusItem *statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
NSImage* icon = [NSImage alloc] initWith ...]
[statusItem setImage:icon];
```

But your image has to be at a correct size (less than 20*20)

Comment: statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength] retain];
 [statusItem setMenu:menu];
 //[statusItem setTitle:@"Notif "];
 [statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
 [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

this is my code and i had added the image to other sources folder

Comment: how can i make a size less then 20*20 ?

Comment: [icon setSize:NSMakeSize(width,height)]. And be sure [NSImage imageNamed:@"image"] does not return nil.

Comment: The image, for non-Retina, has a maximum size of 21x21 rather than 20x20.  For retina, the maximum is 41x41; see [my blog post](http://alastairs-place.net/blog/2013/07/23/nsstatusitem-what-size-should-your-icon-be/) for more.