# OSX Status Bar Image Sizing - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

So i'm having a problem with the image of a `NSStatusBar` item, it seems like the image is pushing away from the rest of the menu items [as you can see in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AokBt.png) But when the menubar is inactive (as in i'm on my other monitor or not in the app) the problem doesn't happen [as you can see in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP13L.png). I'm pretty sure that my code is correct though.

```
statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[statusItem setAction:@selector(openWindow)];
[statusItem setTarget:self];

if ([[[NSAppearance currentAppearance] name] containsString:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark]) {
    [statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"whiteMenu.png"]];
} else {
    [statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"blackMenu.png"]];
}
```

I viewed this question: [Display image in a cocoa status app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411231/display-image-in-a-cocoa-status-app) but the problem persists, so i'm not sure what else to do, thanks for any help! PS: The problem i think is the `NSVariableStatusItemLength`, i tried `NSSquareStatusItemLength` but with no luck, also tried setting it myself, but with the same problem, but with little improvement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also had several problems when implementing a good looking `NSStatusItem` that is displayed in the menu bar.
I got the best results when the following criteria were met for the item (and the accompanying asset)

- The status image should be PDF based
- ... and use the "Template" suffix (more about that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSImage/imageNamed:))
- Meeting the above will give you HiDPI support and proper rendering for both Light & Dark menu bars
- The size of the image should be set to (18.0, 18.0)
- To gain the same highlighting as default OS X items in the status bar, `highlightMode` has to be on and the item has to have an associated `NSMenu`

This snippet will give you a basic application with a nice looking  `NSStatusItem` in the system main menu (I used a system provided image here, but you can get the same results with a custom 18x18 PDF with a "Template" name suffix):

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property NSStatusItem* statusItem;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSImage* statusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameActionTemplate];
    statusImage.size = NSMakeSize(18.0, 18.0);
    self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];
    self.statusItem.image = statusImage;
    self.statusItem.highlightMode = YES;
    self.statusItem.enabled = YES;
    self.statusItem.menu = self.statusMenu;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

Comment: your answer is much better, but it turned out that another answer to my question was just to get rid of the timer that was controlling the status bar, since i had it on a timer to check if the menubar appearance had changed but thanks anyway! Didn't have a clue that i had to use a pdf!